# sym_difference(linestring, polygon, vector<linestring>) does nto work?

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

from [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/sym_difference/sym_difference_3.html) the linear/areal should work. But following code causes compiling err?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/c_array.hpp>
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_C_ARRAY_CS(cs::cartesian)
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp>
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOOST_TUPLE_CS(cs::cartesian)
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> geo2dpoint;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<geo2dpoint> polygon;
typedef boost::geometry::model::linestring<geo2dpoint> linestr;

int main()
{
    double points[][2] = {{2.0, 1.3}, {4.1, 3.0}, {5.3, 2.6}, {2.9, 0.7}, {2.0, 1.3}};
    polygon poly;
    boost::geometry::append(poly, points);
    std::cout << boost::geometry::dsv(poly) << std::endl;
    linestr line1;
    boost::geometry::append(line1, std::vector<geo2dpoint>{{2., 1.f}, {5.f, 3.f}});
    std::cout << boost::geometry::dsv(line1) << std::endl;
    std::vector<linestr> intlines;
    boost::geometry::sym_difference(line1, poly, intlines);
    return 0;
}
```

```
error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
```

Comment: I wonder who downvoted this. They might have supplied a reason. Or they didn't even see that the error was listed as part of the code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I thing the *collection* of linestrings applies to the situation of a `multi_linestring` or `multi_polygon` input.

The following does compile:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0faebcb34b6c0c13)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/linestring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/sym_difference.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>      geo2dpoint;
typedef bg::model::polygon<geo2dpoint>       polygon;
typedef bg::model::linestring<geo2dpoint>    linestr;
typedef bg::model::multi_linestring<linestr> multi_linestr;

int main() {
    polygon poly { { { 2.0, 1.3 }, { 4.1, 3.0 }, { 5.3, 2.6 }, { 2.9, 0.7 }, { 2.0, 1.3 } } };
    multi_linestr line1 { { { 2., 1. }, { 5., 3. } } };

    multi_linestr out;
    bg::sym_difference(line1, poly, out);

    std::cout << bg::dsv(poly) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bg::dsv(line1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << bg::dsv(out) << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
(((2, 1.3), (4.1, 3), (5.3, 2.6), (2.9, 0.7), (2, 1.3)))
(((2, 1), (5, 3)))
(((2, 1), (2.225, 1.15)), ((4.7, 2.8), (5, 3)), ((2.225, 1.15), (4.7, 2.8)))
```

Comment: but the result is apparent wrong. We should at least get 3 linestrings in this case. Since it is a sym operation, we would expect it split polygon too, which should give 5 linestrings.

Comment: turns out there is a bug, the input and output are both need to be multilinestring. If you modify your answer accordingly. I should accept the result.

Comment: @Wang Good spot. I updated the answer. I agree the whole thing is a bit surprising/confusing. I'm not sure that it's a bug, but the docs could certainly be a bit more clear in warning that things that /compile/ might have undefined/unspecified results. Or maybe I just don't understand. Perhaps you can file an issue with the library maintainers (trying to @AdamWulkiewicz)

Comment: @Wang Have you filed an issue to https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/ ? If you haven't, please do so. Thanks!